# Can we cut the videos using FFmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am working on a hobby project using Pi 3. I have bunch of videos (approx 4-5 min long) recorded from Pi camera. Now, I want to cut each video (6-7 seconds) and then want to stitch them back to back. How to do this ?

Answer (score 4):

## concat demuxer

You can use the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) to do this without needing to re-encode.

First make a text file:

```
file '/path/to/video_01.mp4'
inpoint 30
outpoint 35
file '/path/to/video_02.mp4'
inpoint 2
outpoint 6
file '/path/to/video_03.mp4'
inpoint 128
outpoint 142
file '/path/to/video_04.mp4'
inpoint 48
outpoint 51
file '/path/to/video_05.mp4'
inpoint 180
outpoint 200
file '/path/to/video_06.mp4'
inpoint 0
outpoint 8
```

Then run `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

- Note that all segments must be the same format, width x height, frame rate, etc. If they differ see the next method below.
- The in and out points may not be accurate unless your inputs are intra-frame codecs (if you are unsure they probably are not). See the `inpoint` and `output` [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) for details. If frame accuracy is required see the method below.

## concat filter

If you want to perform filtering, such as scaling to conform some segments so they are all the same, then use the [trim](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#trim), [setpts](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts), and [concat](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) filters:

```
ffmpeg -i input0 -i input1 -i input2 -i input3 -i input4 -i input5 \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]trim=3:9,scale=1280:720,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
 [1:v]trim=30:36,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; \
 [2:v]trim=5:12,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2]; \
 [3:v]trim=46:56,scale=1280:720,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v3]; \
 [4:v]trim=2:19,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v4]; \
 [5:v]trim=128:166,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v5]; \
 [v0][v1][v2][v3][v4][v5]concat=n=6:v=1:a=0[v]"
-map "[v]" -c:v h264_omx output.mp4
```

- Filtering will require re-encoding. This example uses the encoder `h264_omx` which utilizes OpenMAX IL hardware to encode. If your `ffmpeg` does not support this, and you want to use it, then see [FFmpeg hardware acceleration on Raspberry PI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40182218/1109017).
- You didn't mention audio, so I assumed there was none. If you need it add the [atrim](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#atrim) filter, adjust the concat `a` value, and add the proper `-map`.